# Error in eval(substitute(x), data, parent.frame()) : argument "data" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, eval

When I run the code below (given by the professor), I got the error

> eval(substitute(x), data, parent.frame()) : 
>     argument "data" is missing, with no default

Also, I see some use the `est=""` and some use the `statistics=""`: which one is the right one to use?

I try to include `library (dplyr)` and `library(statsr)` but that did not solve the problem.

```
back = as.factor(c(rep("correct", 11), rep("wrong", 1)))
inference(back, est = "proportion", type = "ht", method = "simulation",
success = "correct", null = 0.1, alternative = "greater", seed = 654, nsim = 100)
```

Comment: Also, please check the arguments of `?inference`  I couldn't find any `est` argument and it requires a `data` argument

Comment: I think this should just be closed as not reproducible. `akrun` has already identified a critical flaw in the code, since inference requires a `data` argument and none was supplied. Adding data or further code will not solve that problem. There is also the error that the parameter name should be 'statistic' for a value of "proportion" rather than 'est'.

Comment: does anyone have good pointers for "advice reading R help pages"?

Comment: https://github.com/cran/CTFS/blob/master/inst/doc/CTFS.Chpt3.HelpPages.pdf ...

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and helps. It works for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few adjustments (discussed in comments) this seems to work:

- you need to have the focal variable (`back`) as a variable in a data frame, and specify that data frame via the `data` argument
- what you have as the `est` argument should be called `statistic` instead

```
back <- as.factor(c(rep("correct", 11), rep("wrong", 1)))
dd <- data.frame(back)  ## embed the variable in a data frame
inference(back, 
          data = dd,                 ## include data argument
          statistic = "proportion",  ## est -> statistic
          type = "ht", method = "simulation",
          success = "correct", null = 0.1, 
          alternative = "greater", seed = 654, nsim = 100)
```

If you read the help page for `?inference` *carefully*, you'll see that these answers (especially "should I use `est` or `statistic`?") are embedded there ...

Comment: Thank you so much Ben. It works. This is very helpful!

Comment: although the sentiment is appreciated, "thank-you" comments are discouraged on SO; instead, click the check-mark to accept this answer (if it is the best solution to your problem) and upvote any useful answers ...